# OutlinedTextField loses focus in jetpack compose when dropdown is shown

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following code:

```kotlin
Box(
    Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            if (text.length >= 3) {
                viewModel.getSuggestions(text)
            }
        },
        label = { Text("Search") },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        singleLine = true,
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp, 0.dp, 8.dp, 0.dp),
                tint = Color.Unspecified
            )
        },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(50)
    )

    DropdownMenu(expanded = suggestions.value.isNotEmpty(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.92f),
        onDismissRequest = {  }) {

        for (suggestion in suggestions.value) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                viewModel.searchWord(suggestion)
            }) {
                Text(suggestion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a dictionary, on top of the screen there is this `OutlinedTextField`.

When I search for a word I get suggestions based on the input and show them in a `DropdownMenu`.

The problem I am facing is that when the `DropdownMenu` is shown, the keyboard disappears but the focus remains on the `Text` field. How can I solve this problem and most importantly, why is this happening? I know it's redrawing the UI based on the status change but why it's not keeping the keyboard opened.

Answer (score 13):

```
DropdownMenu(properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false))
```

Check this

Comment: Then you can't dismiss the dropdown by clicking outside it seems

Comment: It doesn't work when using ExposedDropdownMenu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using compose `1.+` then you can use `ExposedDropDownMenuBox` instead of `Box` which will display content without losing focus.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ExposedDropdownMenuBoxScope

```
ExposedDropDownMenuBox(
    Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            if (text.length >= 3) {
                viewModel.getSuggestions(text)
            }
        },
        label = { Text("Search") },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        singleLine = true,
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp, 0.dp, 8.dp, 0.dp),
                tint = Color.Unspecified
            )
        },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(50)
    )

    DropdownMenu(expanded = suggestions.value.isNotEmpty(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.92f),
        onDismissRequest = {  }) {

        for (suggestion in suggestions.value) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                viewModel.searchWord(suggestion)
            }) {
                Text(suggestion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```